# c++ get std::vector<int> from std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdtuple

i want to initialize a `const std::vector<int>` member variable in the initializer list of a constructor, given a `std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>` constructor argument. The vector should contain all the first tuple items.

Is there a one-liner that extracts an `std::vector<int>` containing all the first tuple entries from an `std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>` ?

Comment: [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with using [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

Comment: @S.M.: No, that's not it. `std::transform` takes iterators and doesn't return the transformed range.

Comment: @einpoklum I do not get what you mean by  the transformed range.

Comment: @einpoklum true, but the logic can be wrapped in a function, and then the constructor can call the function when initializing the member

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

With C++20 ranges:

```
struct X
{
    const std::vector<int> v;

    template <std::ranges::range R>
        requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, int>
    X(R r)
        : v{r.begin(), r.end()}
    {}

    X(const std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>& vt)
        : X{vt | std::ranges::views::elements<0>}
    {}
};
```

With ranges-v3:

```
struct X
{
    const std::vector<int> v;

    X(const std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>& vt)
        : v{vt | ranges::views::transform([] (auto t) {
                    return std::get<0>(t); })
               | ranges::to<std::vector>()}
    {}
};
```

And a Frankenstein's monster:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>

struct X
{
    const std::vector<int> v;

    X(const std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>>& vt)
        : v{vt | std::ranges::views::elements<0>
               | ranges::to<std::vector>()}
    {}
};
```

Comment: `std::views::elements<0>`…?

Comment: Ah, I was going to say that :-P

Comment: yes, good hint. I will edit

Comment: Note the OP stated the `vector` being created is a `const` member of a class/struct, and a solution is needed that can be used in the constructor's member initialization list. The examples provided do not show that usage.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I have missed the const member part. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @bolov's answer, let's talk about what you might have liked to do, but can't in a one-liner.

- There's the [`to<>()`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/group__group-range.html#ga555b843264809e3765210c42a66d3c3b) function from ranges-v3 from @bolov 's answer - it materializes a range into an actual container (a range is lazily-evaluated, and when you create it you don't actually iterate over the elements). There is no reason it shouldn't be in the standard library, if you ask me - maybe they'll add it 2023?
- You may be wondering - why do I need that `to()`? Can't I just initialize a vector by a range? And the answer is - sort of, sometimes, maybe. Consider this program:

  ```
  #include <vector>
  #include <tuple>
  #include <ranges>

  void foo()
  {
      using pair_type = std::tuple<int, double>;

      std::vector<pair_type> tvec {
           {12, 3.4}, {56, 7.8}, { 90, 91.2}
      };

      auto tv = std::ranges::transform_view(
          tvec, 
          [](const pair_type& p) { return std::get<0>(p);}
      );
      std::vector<int> vec1 { tv.begin(), tv.end() };

      std::vector<std::tuple<int>> vec2 { 
          std::ranges::transform_view{
              tvec,
              [](const pair_type& p) { return std::get<0>(p);} 
          }.begin(),
          std::ranges::transform_view{
              tvec, 
              [](const pair_type& p) { return std::get<0>(p);} 
          }.end()
      };
  }
  ```

  The `vec1` statement will compile just fine, but the `vec2` statement will [fail](https://godbolt.org/z/6PcobMn49) (GodBolt.org). This is surprising (to me anyway)!
- You may also be wondering why you even need to go through ranges at all. Why isn't there a...

  ```
  template <typename Container, typename UnaryOperation>
  auto transform(const Container& container, UnaryOperation op);
  ```

  which constructs the transformed container as its return value? That would allow you to write:

  ```
  std::vector<int> vec3 {
       transform(
           tvec, 
           [](const pair_type& p) { return std::get<0>(p); }
       ) 
  }
  ```

  ... and Bob's your uncle. Well, we just don't have functions in the C++ standard library which take containers. It's either iterator pairs, which is the "classic" pre-C++20 standard library, or ranges.

  Now, the way I've declared the `transform()` function, it is actually tricky/impossible to implement generally, since you don't have a way of converting the type of a container to the same type of container but with a different element. So, instead, let's write something a little easier:

  ```
  template <
      typename T,
      template <typename> class Container,
      typename UnaryOperation
  >
  auto transform(const Container<T>& container, UnaryOperation op)
  {
      auto tv = std::ranges::transform_view(container, op);
      using op_result = decltype(op(*container.begin()));
      return Container<op_result> { tv.begin(), tv.end() };
  }
  ```

  and this [works](https://godbolt.org/z/nnn5bfrra) (GodBolt.org).

Answer (score 2):

Not a one-liner to setup, but certainly one to use - you can write a function to do the conversion, and then the constructor can call that function when initializing the vector member, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<int> convertVec(const std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>> &arg)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(arg.size());
    std::transform(arg.begin(), arg.end(), std::back_inserter(vec),
        [](const std::tuple<int, float> &t){ return std::get<int>(t); }
    );
    return vec;
}

struct Test
{
    const std::vector<int> vec;

    Test(const std::vector<std::tuple<int, float>> &arg)
        : vec(convertVec(arg))
    {
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a one-liner if you use [this library in Github](https://github.com/tirimatangi/LazyExpression).

The code goes like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

#include <LazyExpression/LazyExpression.h>

using std::vector;
using std::tuple;
using std::ref;
using std::cout;

using LazyExpression::Expression;

int main()
{
    // Define test data
    vector<tuple<int, float>> vecTuple { {1,1.1}, {2,2.2}, {3, 3.3} };

    // Initialize int vector with the int part of the tuple (the one-liner :)
    vector<int> vecInt = Expression([](const tuple<int, float>& t) { return std::get<int>(t); }, ref(vecTuple))();

    // print the results
    for (int i : vecInt)
        cout << i << ' ';
    cout << "\n";
}
// Output:  1 2 3
```